# Accept where clause in an advanced function

Tags: powershell, filter, where-clause

Is it possible to pass a `where` clause to an advanced function? An example to make it more clear;

```
$Fruits = @(
    @{
        Name  = 'Kiwi'
        Color = 'Green'
    }
    @{
        Name  = 'Banana'
        Color = 'Yellow'
    }
)

Function Get-Stuff {
    Param (
        [scriptblock]$Filter,
        [hashtable[]]$Collection
    )

    $Collection.Where( { $Filter })
}

Get-Stuff -Filter { $_.Name -eq 'Kiwi' } -Collection $Fruits
```

In this case it would be great if the function can return the same as `$Fruits.Where( { $_.Name -eq 'Kiwi' })`.

Comment: `$test.Where({ $Filter })` -> `$test.Where($Filter)`?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [ansgar-wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) stated in the above comment, you have to remove the outer scriptblock literal (`{}`):

```
$Fruits = @(
    @{
        Name  = 'Kiwi'
        Color = 'Green'
    }
    @{
        Name  = 'Banana'
        Color = 'Yellow'
    }
)

Function Get-Stuff {
    Param (
        [scriptblock]$Filter,
        [hashtable[]]$Collection
    )
    # Subexpression removed.
    $Collection.Where($Filter)
}

Get-Stuff -Filter { $_.Name -eq 'Kiwi' } -Collection $Fruits
```